# Descobrir se o usuário deu print na tela do app

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como o Snapchat faz para saber se o usuário deu um print na tela.

Comment: basta verificar se os botões do print(Home e Power no meu caso) foram acionados

Comment: E quando o comando é via software? Alguns aparelhos tem atalhos na barra de ferramentas...

Comment: De uma olhada na pergunta assinalada acima

Comment: Então, pelo que entendi na resposta do tópico assinalado acima, ele verifica quando se tem uma imagem na tela. Mas eu quero por exemplo descobrir se uma RecyclerView foi "printada", como ficaria? 